# Limit of a sequence of limit points

Tags: real-analysis

I am asked to prove the following statement:
"If $(p_n)$ is a sequence of limit points of a set $A\in\mathbb{R}$ and $p_n\rightarrow p$, then $p$ is a limit point of $A$ too.

I want to know if my proof is complete and accurate:

Since $(p_n)$ is a sequence of limit points, then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\exists a\in A$ such that $0<|p_n-a|<\epsilon /2$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Also, since $p_n\rightarrow p$, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N \implies |p_n-p|< \epsilon/2$.

So, $\forall \epsilon>0$ and $n>N$, we have that $\exists a \in A$ such that $$|p-a|=|p-p_n+p_n-a|\leq|p-p_n|+|p_n-a|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$$

which means that $p$ is a limit point of $A$.

Comment: Doesn't your $a$ depend on $n$?

Comment: @asdf Yes, but I don't think that that makes my answer illegitimate. I still produce, for all $\epsilon$, an $a\in A$ such that $0<|p-a|<\epsilon$, which I believe shows that p is a limit point of A.

Comment: It would be better to make it explicit that $a$ depends on $n$: $\exists a_n \in A$ such that $0 < |p_n - a_n| < \epsilon/2$. Either that, or note that all you need to show is that for every $\epsilon$ there is some $a\in A$ with $0 < |p - a| <\epsilon$, which just requires showing it for some $n > N$, not all $n > N$. That only clarifies the proof, though. What you have is okay as far as that goes. The one thing that is missing is showing that $0 < |a - p|$. That is, $a$ can always be chosen to be different from $p$.